Publicly "commit" to a number to every node in P2P network
Let's assume we have a P2P network of node A, B, C, and D. Node A sends the number 55 to node B and generates a hash for that number and shares it with B, C, and D. B shares that number with C and D and they validate it using the hashes they received. How does one prevent A from generating different hashes for each node?

What is is your concern about A sharing different hashes to C/D, beyond those nodes not agreeing with B on the value that A sent?
